# JUnit/Spring/Hibernate - No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource]

Tags: java, hibernate, junit

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JobSeekerServiceTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests.setDataSource(javax.sql.DataSource); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:385)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:82)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:199)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:253)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:216)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:82)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:60)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:67)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:162)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests.setDataSource(javax.sql.DataSource); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
>       ... 26 more
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1261)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1009)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:600)
>       ... 28 more

### Test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)  
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath*:spring-config.xml") 
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=true,transactionManager="txManager")
@Transactional
public class JobSeekerServiceTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests{

    private JobSeekerDao jobseekerDao = new JobSeekerDao();

    @Test
    public void testGetCandidateForEmail(){
        JobSeeker result = new JobSeeker();
        JobSeeker expected = new JobSeeker();
        expected.setName("Dummy Job seeker 1");expected.setEmail("email@yahoo.com");expected.setCity("City");expected.setPhone("04523122");

        result = jobseekerDao.getCandidateForEmail("email@yahoo.com");
        assertEquals(result, expected);
    }
}
```

### JobSeekerDao

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public JobSeeker getCandidateForEmail(String email) {
        LOGGER.debug("Searching the candidate after an email:"+email);
        Session session = getCurrentSession();

        List<JobSeeker> candidates = session.createQuery("from JobSeeker where email=?")
                .setParameter(0, email)
                .list();


        if (candidates.size() > 0) {
            return candidates.get(0);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

### Spring-Config.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">  
            <property name="driverClassName"    value="${database.driver}" />  
            <property name="url"                value="${database.url}" />  
            <property name="username"           value="${database.user}" />  
            <property name="password"           value="${database.password}" />  
        </bean>  

        <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.awinta.hrms"/>

            <property name="hibernateProperties">  
                <props>  
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>  
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">${hibernate.use_sql_comments}</prop>

                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>

                    <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">${hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults}</prop>

                    <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">${hibernate.connection.pool_size}</prop>
                </props>  
            </property>  
        </bean> 

        <bean id="txManager" 
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" 
            name="txManager">  
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        </bean>
```

Any ideas why I am getting this error? I am newbie in Spring,Hibernate,JUnit. In conclusion I think I should do somehow like this. Or how should I do this test class?

## UPDATE

I read somewhere cause the problem is extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests, and without it I don`t get anymore this error.

Answer (score -1):

Exception is letting you know that the test class cannot find any suitable JDBC driver. You should add a JDBC driver to the test classpath to fix this issue

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I tried, I add the Postgres jar files to the test classpath but the error remains.